# Using droplevel in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My table has two columns.  I'm new to this but previously  I have used droplevel to remove a column

```
players = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Standard Stats")

players[0]
```

This gave me my table as expected but with two headers

I understand that

```
players.columns = players.columns.droplevel()
```

would remove the top header

but I got

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 players.columns = players.columns.droplevel()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I would be really grateful for your assistance

Thanks for the reply FlyingTeller.   `players` does exactly what I expected it to do

- `players`       Shows a list of the raw data and
- `players[0]`    Formats it into a table

I'm not sure what I can amend ?

EDIT :

I've added `[0]` to my code and used `StringIO`, so that my code now reads like this :

```
players = pd.read_html(StringIO(data.text), match="Standard Stats")[0]
players[0]
```

This should be fine, right?
But I get the error code:

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most 
 recent call last)
 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in 
 Index.get_loc(self, key)
 3801 try:
 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
 3803 except KeyError as err:

 File index.pyx:153, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 File index.pyx:182, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 File pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7081, in 
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

 File pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7089, in 
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

 KeyError: 0

 The above exception was the direct cause of the following 
 exception:

 KeyError                                  Traceback (most 
  recent call last)
  Cell In[17], line 1
  1 players[0]

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4089, in 
 DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
 4087 if is_single_key:
 4088     if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
 4089         return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
 4090     indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
 4091     if is_integer(indexer):

 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4147, in 
 DataFrame._getitem_multilevel(self, key)
  4145 def _getitem_multilevel(self, key):
  4146     # self.columns is a MultiIndex
  4147     loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  4148     if isinstance(loc, (slice, np.ndarray)):
  4149         new_columns = self.columns[loc]

 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py:3040, in 
  MultiIndex.get_loc(self, key)
  3037     return mask
  3039 if not isinstance(key, tuple):
 3040     loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
 3041     return _maybe_to_slice(loc)
  3043 keylen = len(key)

 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py:3391, in M 
 MultiIndex._get_level_indexer(self, key, level, indexer)
  3388         return slice(i, j, step)
 3390 else:
 3391     idx = self._get_loc_single_level_index(level_index, 
  key)
  3393     if level > 0 or self._lexsort_depth == 0:
  3394         # Desired level is not sorted
  3395         if isinstance(idx, slice):
  3396             # test_get_loc_partial_timestamp_multiindex

 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py:2980, in 
 MultiIndex._get_loc_single_level_index(self, level_index, key)
 2978     return -1
 2979 else:
 2980     return level_index.get_loc(key)

 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3809, in 
 Index.get_loc(self, key)
  3804     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
 3805         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
 3806         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
  3807     ):
  3808         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
 3809     raise KeyError(key) from err
 3810 except TypeError:
 3811     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error w   
 ill raise
  3812     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and 
 re-raise
  3813     #  the TypeError.
  3814     self._check_indexing_error(key)

  KeyError: 0
```

Ok. Many thanks for the help so far. I'm confident this will be my final question on this.

I now have two data tables (players and shooting) which I'd to merge together.  (Basically add a field called Distance from shooting to players)

My understanding is that I need to :

team_data = players.merge(shooting[["Distance"]], on="Player")

However I get an error message of :

---

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most 
 recent call last)
 ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11188\547657476.py in ?()
 1 team_data = players.merge(shooting[["Dist"]], on="Player")

 ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\frame.py in ?(self, right, how, on, 
  left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, 
 copy, indicator, validate)
  10801         validate: MergeValidate | None = None,
  10802     ) -> DataFrame:
  10803         from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
  10804 
 > 10805         return merge(
  10806             self,
 10807             right,
 10808             how=how,

 ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in ?(left, right, how, 
  on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, 
   suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   166             validate=validate,
  167             copy=copy,
   168         )
  169     else:
--> 170         op = _MergeOperation(
    171             left_df,
   172             right_df,
   173             how=how,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in ?(self, left, right, 
 how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, 
 suffixes, indicator, validate)
790             self.right_join_keys,
791             self.join_names,
   792             left_drop,
  793             right_drop,
```

--> 794         ) = self.*get_merge* keys()
795
796         if left_drop:
797             self.left =
self.left._drop_labels_or_levels(left_drop)

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in ?(self)
  1293                         # Then we're either Hashable or a 
 wrong-length arraylike,
  1294                         #  the latter of which will raise
  1295                         rk = cast(Hashable, rk)
  1296                         if rk is not None:
-> 1297                             
 right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  1298                         else:
  1299                             # work-around for 
 merge_asof(right_index=True)
   1300                             
 right_keys.append(right.index._values)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, key, axis)
  1906             values = self.xs(key, 
axis=other_axes[0])._values
  1907         elif self._is_level_reference(key, axis=axis):
   1908             values = 
self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
  1909         else:
-> 1910             raise KeyError(key)
   1911 
   1912         # Check for duplicates
 1913         if values.ndim > 1:

  KeyError: 'Player'
```

Comment: check `type(players)`. It looks to be a list, not a dataframe. Possibly you have overwriten it accidentally with a list variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the previous `AttributeError` and the following `KeyError` problems are caused by the very last line `players[0]` in your code. At first, it supposed to be like `players = players[0]` because [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of data frames. You corrected the code by adding `[0]` after `pd.read_html(...)`. But after that the line `players[0]` addresses not a `list` but a `DataFrame`, so zero is expected to be a name of a column, which seems to be an error. All you need is to remove the line `players[0]` in your updated code, or correct it in the previous version, like:

```
players = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Standard Stats")
players = players[0]
players.columns = players.columns.droplevel()
```